# Evitar a desinstalação de aplicativo mesmo após restauração de fábrica

Tags: android

Como desenvolver um app que, mesmo após o aparelho ser restaurado ele continue instalado, igual os apps das operadoras de celular? Desde já, obrigado.

Comment: Na verdade, os apps são integrados ao android, por isso são reinstalados ao restaurar os aparelhos de fábrica. Pra integrar um app ao android, você precisa praticamente recompilar a rom do android com seu app incluso. Mas hoje em dia, quando um usuario restaura o aparelho, todos os apps voltam, após ele logar na conta, então não creio que você precise chegar a tanto.

Comment: Acredito que tem jeito sim, pois o Cerberus faz, mas precisa de root.

Comment: creio quase que com certeza que o seu app necessitará de permissões ROOT.

Answer (score 2):

Isso só é possível quando você é proprietário da **room** do aparelho. Esse método funciona nas operadoras pois normalmente cada operadora possui uma **room customizada** com os aplicativos que elas acham necessários para o usuário. Infelizmente nem sempre isso é verdade. Porém se sua preocupação é que o usuário ao resetar o aparelho ficar sem o seu aplicativo, o **Google** armazena todos os seus aplicativos na sua conta podendo restaurar eles.